# PuTTY does not write @ - django Admin createsuperuser

Tags: django, admin, putty

Iam using PuTTY for my ssh connection to my webapp via Windows.
My keyboard is in german.

My problem is while I try to create an Superuser "python manage.py createsuperuser" it is not possible for me to write the @ (STRG + ALT + Q) 
sign in the emailadress.
Instead of @ it gives me a ^[. I already tried many other combinations also the english one, but none of them worked

Comment: I also deinstalled putty, but it didn't changed

Comment: Here's a couple of work arounds. Try copy and pasting the the `@` sign. Or, just enter an empty string for the email address, it's not required. You can then log into the web interface and change the email address there.

Comment: Ah thank you. I thought it is not possible to use copy paste commands in the command prompt. Now I looked for other ways instead of STRG + C and STRG + V. So just STRG + V outside of the prompt and then right mouseclick. PROBLEM SOLVED